# Bulletproof windows in GTA V (Singleplayer)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am currently only aware of 3 vehicles with bulletproof windows:

1. The police transporter van - the one that lays stingers on the road (however the side windows are not bulletproof and only have bulletproof coating)
2. The police (SWAT?) van - that appears at higher wanted levels and also has bulletproof windows (all of them are bulletproof)
3. A third vehicle which was gifted to "returning" people, who I am not.

The issue with the above police vehicles is they cannot be stored in 6-car garages, and they can only just fit into a characters safehouse garage. In addition, they are slow, clumsy and don't even have bulletproof tires.

So, in singleplayer, are there any vehicles (that I can buy, steal or upgrade) that come with bulletproof windows?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the only "armored vehicles" attainable in single player are the Rhino tank and the Duke O'Death (DoD is only available to "returning players" and those lucky enough to actually spawn the "Duel" random event and get away with the car). You can't even buy the stock Karuma (non-armored) in story mode.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware there are a number of cars that you can purchase in the singleplayer that are bulletproof. Have you checked the wiki or rockstar's own website about this?

The first car that comes to mind is the Karuma, its an average sized saloon car that is completely bullet and rocket proof including the tires.

[Here is the link](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Armored_Vehicles) to the wiki that details all the "Armoured" cars available. You can peruse them as you need.

I'm not sure if you can buy all of the listed cars in the single player but I know that you can definitely buy most. Just go to the web browser on your phone and then onto the car supplier that you want.

You will need to have purchased a garage before hand otherwise the vehicle will not be delivered to you.

**EDIT:** You can also find a duke o death in a rusted out storage shed at the very southern tip of the Murrieta Oil Field in southern Los Santos, free of charge. After this you can buy the car from the Army website. [Link to the forum post about this.](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/805605-grand-theft-auto-v/70690013)

Comment: Almost all of these armored vehicles are GTA Online exclusive - and I believe those duke of death spawn locations are only available after a random event and/or being a returning user.

Comment: Have you attempted to purchase any of the vehicles in the story mode?

Comment: I have looked up the first few, however I haven't looked up all of them as the wiki itself will state if the vehicle is available in single player (as it differentiates between GTA V online and just GTA V).